# Изменение цвета линий в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, color

Как изменить **только** цвет линий(полосок) в `ListView`?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6544723/5812238

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## В файле разметки:

Свойством [`android:divider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:divider) устанавливаем цвет разделителя:

```
android:divider="#RRGGBB"
```

**Вместе с этим** необходимо установить высоту разделителя свойством [`android:dividerHeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:dividerHeight) (иначе разделитель не будет виден):

```
android:dividerHeight="4px"
```

Полный пример:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#RRGGBB"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## В коде

Используя методы [`ListView.setDivider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), [`ListView.setDividerHeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDividerHeight(int)) и один из классов градиента:

- [`ColorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) для обычного разделителя:

  ```
  list.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0xAARRGGBB));
  list.setDividerHeight(4);
  ```

  (используя `context.getResources().getColor(R.color.некоторый_id)` можно получить цвет, заданный в ресурсах)
- [`GradientDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html):

  ```
  ListView list = ...
  int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; // красный цвет для примера
  list.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
  list.setDividerHeight(4);
  ```

В обоих сначала нужно установить цвет разделителя, а **затем** его высоту, иначе разделитель не будет виден.